# Why is grouping sets query taking longer than UNION query in Postgres 9.5.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to improve a postgres query that is producing a table based on the union of 3 select statements with a group by clause.  How can I speed up the grouping sets query?  Is it the JOIN clause that is the cause of the slowdown?  I thought grouping sets was supposed to be more performant out of the box than union.

Here is the first part of the query common to both the Union and Grouping sets query:

```
  SELECT data_fetch.snapshot_id,
    count(*) AS movie_count,
    sum(data_fetch.view_count) AS view_count,
    sum(data_fetch.comment_count) AS comment_count,
    sum(data_fetch.like_count) AS like_count,
    sum(data_fetch.dislike_count) AS dislike_count,
    sum(data_fetch.share_count) AS share_count,
    COALESCE(movies.category, 3) AS movie_category,
    COALESCE(movies.type, 'movie') AS movie_type
   FROM (data_fetch JOIN movies ON ((movies.id = data_fetch.movie_id)))
```

Below is the output of the 2 queries from a raw sql EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE run in the rails console:

**Grouping Sets Query**

https://explain.depesz.com/s/XJE5

**Union query:**

https://explain.depesz.com/s/TdFE

Comment: These queries, especially the second one, are not remotely _readable_, and at your rep level you should be asking better questions.

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen, is there a good tool to break this up, or is it something I should do by hand?  It is literally the output from records_array.values from `records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Comment: Format by hand perhaps...or else some other SO user will have to format.

Comment: Manual...Hopefully this is better...

Comment: looking at some other questions where postgresql explain output have been posted will help you figure out how to change your question. Really as it is, this is worth flagging unclear what you are asking

Comment: Yes. There is only one query in the question, but an execution plan without a query is pretty useless. Moreover, the execution plans are unreadable. Use `psql` to create execution plans.

Comment: Please [**format**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the execution plan properly (using the `{}` button) - the indention and line breaks **do** matter (a lot). Or upload the plans to http://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: if you have problems with `psql` try using ` EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,VERBOSE,FORMAT JSON) ` or xml, to make it parseable